# Query set sorting in python using key

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
temp = [{'name':'abcd3', "id":3},
        {'name':'abcd', "id":1},
        {'name':'abcd4', "id":4},
        {'name':'abcd2', "id":2},]
```

How to sort temp using id.

Comment: `sorted(temp,key=lambda x:x['id'])`

Comment: Well, **What you have tried so far**?

Comment: @RahulKP Thanx it's Working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort by using the sort method on the object. ie

`temp.sort()`

Solution which is none destructive or does not mutate object use

`sorted(temp,key=lambda x:x['id'])`

Comment: which python version are you using? It works for me. I use python 2.7.13 @RahulKP